# Make an a child div the same height as parent even after parent has resized

Tags: jquery, height, autoresize

So I have this thing that I am building, and what happens is when a user clicks on a li element, it opens up a popup window that is the same height as the main parent container.

```
<div class="tools">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a>Click Me to Open Popup Window</a>
         <div class="popup">
             <header>Title Goes Here</header>
             <ul>
                List elements that clickable and close the popup.
             </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have everything working correctly using this code:

```
// this is the js that sets the height of the popup.
    var popHeight = $('.tools').height() - 23;
    $('.popup ul').css({'height': popHeight + 'px'});

// This is the js that reveals the popup.
    $('.tools ul li a').live('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.popup').addClass('reveal');
    });
```

The basic idea is that the ul of the popup has to be the same height as that of .tools container minus the height of the header.

Now, the only problem that occurs is that the height .tools can change because elements are dynamically added to it. So if you have already opened the popup once, then the .tools div height changes, and you click to open the popup again, its height will be the same as it was the first time, it will not resize to be the same height as the new height of .tools.

So what can I do with the jquery so that it will recheck the height of .tools before popping up so that it is always the correct height?

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

I forgot to include the js that reveals the popup on click. so I added that above. What happens is the popup is hidden on load, then when you click on the a tag, the popup gets the class .reveal added, which then makes it show up.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the **<a>** it fires the **onclick event**. I think you could bind your JQuery code to this event... something like:

```
$('div.tools > ul > li > a').click(function(){  /* put your code here */  });
```

I did not tested it here, but I think it might help.

Comment: Whoops! Check my post again. I realize I forgot to add the js I use to actually make the popup show up.